# How to convert NULLIF and COALESCE in Slick Scala

Tags: scala, slick

I was getting division by zero error when doing aggregation division in slick.

SQL:

```
SELECT person, SUM(item) / SUM(cash) as avg FROM peron_item GROUP by person
```

So I modified the query in sql as following.

```
SELECT person, COALESCE (SUM(item) / NULLIF(SUM(cash), 0) , 0) as avg, FROM peron_item GROUP by person
```

How to achieve the same thing in Slick?

My current slick scala code looks like this,

```
val action = query.groupBy(row => (row.person)).map { case (key, value) =>(key._1, value.map{_.item}.sum / value.map(_.cash).sum,)}.result
val finalResult = session.database.run(action)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you can transform your data just implementing your own `coalesce` and `nullif` functions:

```
def optionalDivide[A](dividend: A, divider: Option[A])
  (divideOp: (A, A) => A): Option[A] = 
  divider.map{ d => divideOp(dividend, d)}

def nullIf[A](actual: A, expected: A): Option[A] =
  Option(actual).filter(_ != expected)

def coalesce[A](values: List[Option[A]], defaultValue: A): A = 
  values.find(_.isDefined).flatten.getOrElse(defaultValue)

val action = query.groupBy(row => (row.person)).map {
  case (key, value) => (key._1,  
    coalesce(
      List(
        optionalDivide(
          value.map{_.item}.sum, 
          nullIf(value.map(_.cash).sum, 0)
        )((x, y) => x / y)
      ), 0
    )
  )
}.result
val finalResult = session.database.run(action)
```

but one thing I can't understand: why you are trying implement sql operations instead of just using properly `query` to your database.